# Many to one relation, select only rows which ancestor met all criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

First I will show You architecture of tables.

```
 Table "public.questionare"
      Column        |          Type         |                           
--------------------+-----------------------+
 id                 | integer               | 




Table "public.questionareacceptance"
         Column          |          Type         |                         
-------------------------+-----------------------+
 id                      | integer               | 
 questionare_id          | integer               |
 accept_id               | integer               |
 impact_id               | integer               |
```

Table `questionareacceptance` contains:

```
id  | questionare_id | accept_id|       impact_id  |
----+----------------+----------+------------------+
1   |1               |1         |                  |
2   |1               |1         | 1                |
3   |1               |1         | 1                |
4   |2               |          | 1                |
5   |3               |1         | 1                |
6   |4               |1         | 1                |
7   |4               |1         | 1                |
```

What I am trying to get is a list of `questionare ID` where in each `questionareacceptance` fields `accept_id` and `impact_id` are not `NULL`

My query looks like:

```
SELECT q.id AS quest,
    qa.id AS accepted
FROM questionare q,
    questionareacceptance qa
WHERE q.id = qa.questionare_id
    AND qa.accept_id IS NOT NULL
    AND qa.impact_id IS NOT NULL;
```

But the result is as fallows:

```
      quest         |          accepted     |                           
--------------------+-----------------------+
 1                  |1                      | 
 1                  |2                      | 
 1                  |3                      | 
 2                  |4                      | 
 3                  |5                      | 
 4                  |6                      | 
 4                  |7                      |
```

But the result that should be returned are only `3` and `4` others have `impact_id` or `accept_id` null.

Can anyone point me where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query could be written with not exists:

```
select
    q.id as quest, qa.id as accepted
from questionare as q
    inner join questionareacceptance as qa on qa.questionare_id = q.id
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from questionareacceptance as tqa
        where
           tqa.questionare_id = q.id and
           (tqa.accept_id is null or tqa.impact_id is null)
    )
```

but I think faster one would using window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select
        q.id as quest, qa.id as accepted,
        sum(case when qa.accept_id is not null and qa.impact_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by q.id) as cnt1,
        count(*) over(partition by q.id) as cnt2
    from questionare as q
        inner join questionareacceptance as qa on qa.questionare_id = q.id
)
select quest, accepted
from cte
where cnt1 = cnt2
```

actually looks like you don't need join at all:

```
with cte as (
    select
        qa.questionare_id as quest, qa.id as accepted,
        sum(case when qa.accept_id is not null and qa.impact_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by qa.questionare_id) as cnt1,
        count(*) over(partition by qa.questionare_id) as cnt2  
    from questionareacceptance as qa
)
select quest, accepted
from cte
where cnt1 = cnt2;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8aaea/17)</kbd>**

Comment: How did you add that awesome sqlfiddle demo button?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu it's `<kbd>` tag

Comment: I don't think the windowed functions would be faster. The execution plan is a lot simpler when using `not exists`

Comment: @GarethD yeah, may be you're right, haven't checked it. It could depends on indexes on the table, but I'm usually assume that using one table scan is faster